# Express not handling conditionals

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, conditional-statements

I am new on Express. I have the following code:

```
const { response } = require("express");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.get("/api/products/:id", function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id;

  if (id === 1) {
    res.json(id);
  }
});
```

However, every time I set the conditional if the server don't respond and just stay processing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: use `if (id === '1') {` or `if (id == 1) {`, as `id` is a string (you should also be sending a response in an `else` block)

Comment: Surprisingly, the [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params) documentation isn't explicit about this, but the parameter values are always strings as Express has no way of knowing whether you want it to parse strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

req.params are always strings;

```
app.get("/api/products/:id", function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id;

  if (id === '1') { // look here, the single quotes around 1 -> '1'
    res.json(id);
  } else {
    res.json({message: 'Wrong param'}) // respond also if id is not '1', otherwise the client will still wait for a response when param is different by '1'
  }
})
```